# Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2 without update Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I execute the command:
`rails s` in my project, the console display the message:

> Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

I executed the command:

brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
rbenv install --list 
and the version `2.1.2` appears in the list.

Then, I executed the command:  `rbenv rehash`, but appears the same message when I executed the command:
`rails s`.
In my `Gemfile` file, is listed the:
`ruby '2.1.2'`
but I'm not looking replace this value  with the previous version.

And if I execute :

`rvm use 2.1.2`
Is displayed:

```
 Warning! PATH is not properly set up,
 '/Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin' is not at first place,
          usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
          it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
          to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.2'. Using /Users/Jarvis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2 Warning!
 Executable 'ruby' missing, something went wrong with this ruby
 installation! Warning! Executable 'gem' missing, something went wrong
 with this ruby installation! Warning! Executable 'irb' missing,
 something went wrong with this ruby installation!
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `rbenv` alongside `rvm` may very well cause issues...

Comment: I'm with D-side. My suggestion would be to use either rbenv or rvm, but not both. Does your project have a .ruby-version file?

Comment: @NickM really, no. I'll uninstall `rvm` and keep `rbenv`

Comment: Thanks @D-side and @NickM really keep `rbenv` and `rvm` have conflicts. I removed `rvm` and now it's working perfectly.

Comment: To remove RVM completely, here's what we use: https://github.com/SixArm/sixarm_unix_shell_scripts/blob/master/rvm-uninstall-danger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM and RBenv are actually similar tools. There are no practical reasons to keep them alongside each other in one session (and on one machine most of the time). They both rely on modifying `PATH` environment variable to get the Ruby and supplementary binaries closer for easy use.

And that's what RVM complains about: `PATH` is not what it expects to be. That said, RBEnv apparently tampered with it. Since these tools do their best to overtake `ruby`, `gem`, `irb` and stuff, they may very well conflict with each other on occasions.

So, remove one of them. Which one, is up to you. Removing RVM is as easy as:

```
rvm implode
```

...that will remove RVM's files, rubies and gems for them, but you might also want to inspect `.bash_profile`, `.profile` and `.bashrc` for relevant lines.

The uninstallation process for RBEnv seems to be the manual one: remove the folder, review the files listed above for relevant lines.